# How vf controller redirect to another page

Tags: apex

I have a Apex Controller for a VF page. I want to redirect my page to another one, only if I cannot get a specific parameter from the URL. current page: /apex/profile?uname='test;, if i get the null value from the url then it's redirect to /apex/home page.below is my code.

```
public class HomePageController {

public HomePageController()
{
  String unameParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uname');
  if(unameparam == null)
  {
    // calling logout method to redirect to home page.      
    Logout();
  }
}

public PageReference Logout() {
         System.debug('RCHOME ###');
         PageReference mainHome= Page.rc_home; 
         mainHome.setRedirect(true);
         return mainHome;
}
```

if i get the null value from url it's executing `Logout()` method successfully but it's not redirecting to home page.

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not redirect user from controller> Call this method from Page's Action attribute and check value of URL and if it is null then redirect it to home page. It will work for you.
Code sample

```
public HomePageController()
{
  String unameParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uname');
  if(unameparam == null)
  {
    // calling logout method to redirect to home page.      
    Logout();
  }
}

public PageReference Logout() {
     String unameParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uname');
  if(unameparam == null)
  {
         System.debug('RCHOME ###');
         PageReference mainHome= Page.rc_home; 
         mainHome.setRedirect(true);
         return mainHome;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Sharma, thanks for your help, it's working but it's always redirecting to page2 even uname not null or not empty. Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: you don't put any condition . First check if your parameter is null same as you are checking the constructor.

Comment: sorry, it's not working please see my code below.

Page: <apex:page controller="redirectcontroller" action="{!HomePage}">
</apex:page>   

URL: https://TEST.visual.force.com/apex/page1?uname='test' it's redirecting to page2. Please see the controller below.

Comment: public without sharing class redirectcontroller {
    public redirectcontroller()
    {
        String uparam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uname');
        System.debug('UPARAM ###:'+uparam);
        
        if(uparam == null)
        {
           HomePage();
        }
    }
    
    
    public Pagereference HomePage()
    {
         System.debug('RCHOME ###');
         PageReference mainHome= Page.Page2; 
         mainHome.setRedirect(true);
         return mainHome;
    }
}

Comment: I have update my comment with code sample you can take help from that. I am sure it will work for you.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine.